# Education Section Doesn't Handle Multiple Degrees Well

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, jobs

In my [CV on Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/kengray), I have three of my degrees listed from Mizzou, but they show up in a horizontal format which is hard to read at a glance.

Is there a better way to display them?

Comment: We'll discuss with our super-designer, Jin Yang - http://stackoverflow.com/users/53037/jin

Comment: By the way, "shear" is a verb (or occasionally a noun) and "sheer" is the adjective. It should be "sheer artistry".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How should this show up?  I'm still only seeing one line for my degrees?

Answer (score 1):

We now use a 2 line format for this so there's more room for them to "breathe"

Comment: see 'answer' below.